# Github release zip containing only partial code from repo

Tags: git, github, download, zip, release

while the Github provide a [way to releasing software](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases), I don't know if possible to specify just some files of the current master repository to be released and be downloaded as a zip file.

I want to offer users the possibility to download a certain folder/files from the whole repository, like say; I have 3 files in my repoo, `file_1.js`, `file_2.js`,  `file_3.js` - I want to make `file_3.js` a downloadable release as a zip file `my_app_v1.0.zip`.

How is that possible?

Thanks for any ideas :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The release is a way to attached binaries to a tag in your Git repo (in addition of the archive of the source code itself).
You can attach as many binaries as you want, which means you can build and package as many releases as you need.
One of those binaries can include a partial set of your repo codebase, should you chose to package it that way.

But a release isn't dynamically packaged, and it doesn't necessarily include the repo sources. It generally include the result of a repo build. Or any other element that you want to be part of a release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to attach external binaries to a tag; I just need to create downloadable zip file releases based on **some files I specify** from the repo. I updated my question :)

Comment: I understand. But the way you provide that "downloadable zip file" is by attaching it to a release. Because a release  is a way to tie binaires to a specific version of your repo, from which you built said binaires.

Comment: "I want to make file_3.js a downloadable release as a zip file my_app_v1.0.zip. Is it possible?". It is possible if you build that zip file yourself, and attach it to a release. Or you would have to store it elsewhere, like as a result of a Travis CI (https://travis-ci.org/) build, for instanced (and this wouldn't be using GitHub release at all)

Answer (score 6):

> while the Github provide a way to releasing software, I don't know if
>   possible to specify just some files of the current master repository
>   to be released and be downloaded as a zip file.
>
> How is that possible?
>
> Thanks for any ideas :)

When a new release is created, the github platform creates for us two downloadable zipped files: ***Source code (.zip)*** and ***Source code (.tar.gz)*** both containing the whole repository source code. The above created files ***can't be deleted*** by user using the online user interface (www.githuh.com). So let's go on.

When you create or edit a release, you can upload any kind of files from your hard drive (***you can't link files from your github repo to the release***, in other words, you have to download the files from repo to your hard drive!!). In other words, ***you can upload what files as you want***. BUT, folders!!! ;-)

If you have already created the release, you can click "Edit release" to manage (add/remove) files attached to your release.

In ***summary***, the idea is:

1. creating, in your hard drive, a zip file containing what you want from your repository;
2. upload the created zip file by click on create/edit release buttons.

Comment: Thanks @baudo2048, surprisingly, I couldn't find this documented elsewhere.  I must have looked in the wrong places ... but anyway, cheers! z