# How to exclude files and folders from being included in source code of git release?

Tags: git, github

I have few files and folders to be excluded from my release in git. I noticed that when I download the source code, few files that's not necessary were included. I have included the folder in .gitignore but it doesn't work. How to exclude them via web?

Comment: @grg : nope, I'm trying to exclude files from being included when you click "Source code" in releases via web interface

Comment: Oops, that is not the duplicate I meant to suggest, I intended this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822564/github-release-zip-containing-only-partial-code-from-repo

Comment: The solution is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443948/2088798